# How do I find attribution for a chess problem I have come across and want to ask a question about?

Tags: discussion

Let’s say I wanted to ask a question about a chess problem I found, to learn about the strategy behind it, but I also want to give attribution to the author. However, I don’t know who the author is and extensive searching hasn’t brought up anything useful. What can/should I do to find the author then? Are there any known tools that could help aid me?

Answer (score 2):

One way that you can find who created a chess problem is by using chess problem databases, which are more or less giant Wikipedias for chess problems. Here are a few that are easy to use and widely used, along with small guides on how to use them.

1. [Yet Another Chess Problem Database](https://www.yacpdb.org/#static/home)

Note: Instead of the English notation “N” for knight, YACPBD (the site’s acronym) uses “S” for the knight, as it reserves “N” for the fairy chess pieces called [nightriders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightrider_(chess).

2. [Die Schwalbe Chess Database Server](https://pdb.dieschwalbe.de/index.jsp)

Forewarning: The Die Schwalbe database is a German site that uses [German chess notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)#Piece_names_in_various_languages).

(More coming soon)